# axis1 and axis2 Client SOAP logging - ADB binding

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, axis

I am new to Web Service.

I have one web service and that service is consumed by both the stubs generated using axis1 and axis2.

I want to Log outgoing raw SOAP request messages and incoming SOAP response at CLIENT side for both axis1 and axis2.
I have implemented at server end for both axis1 and axis2, it works fine.

My consumer is normal JAVA project.

I didn't find any proper steps how to do it.

Few links explained but much in abstract way.
I tried 
http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/AxisClientConfiguration/ViewSOAPMessages

Below linked explain very well but I am not getting Locator class in mine(I generated stub using Eclipse)
http://proghowto.com/axis-client-request-and-response-logging

if some one implemented it or has some link which explains it, Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the way how to do later....I have posted the same here if anybody in search of same stuff

http://servletsguide.blogspot.in/